# Mudanças de texto na label com switch

Tags: java, swing, switch

Sabem aquela conversa inicial do Pokemon?

> "Bem vindo ao mundo pokemon" - ENTER
>   "Você é garota ou garoto?" -ENTER
>   CONTINUA....

Então, estou tentando fazer um pelo swing do Java, no momento tá assim:

```
private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jLabel1.setText(mudarTexto());
        //i++;
    }                                    


    public String mudarTexto(){
            //jTexto.setText("Olá,bem vindo ao mundo pokémon");
            int i = 0;
            switch(i){
                case 0:
                    c ="oi";
                case 1:
                    c  =  "Olá,bem vindo ao mundo pokémon";
                case 2:
                    c = "Você é garoto ou garota?";
                case 3:
                    c = "aa";
                default:
                    c = "c";

            }

            return c ;
    }
```

Porém o `switch` não lê meu `i` como zero , ele só printa a ultima instrução do switch que no caso é default, se a última fosse o case 3, então ele que seria printado,como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto acontece pois você não está saindo do `switch` ao encontrar o `case` correto, por isso, ele passa por todos. Altere adicionando as "paradas" entre os cases:

```
switch(i){
    case 0:
        c ="oi";
        break;
    case 1:
        c  =  "Olá,bem vindo ao mundo pokémon";
        break;
    case 2:
        c = "Você é garoto ou garota?";
        break;
    case 3:
        c = "aa";
        break;
    default:
        c = "c";
}
```

Repare que no `default` não foi adicionado, pois ali já irá sair do `switch` de qualquer jeito.

Comment: po, vdd, vlw aí

Comment: @Dr.G que bom que ajudou. Você também pode marcar a resposta como aceita, para servir de referencia para outras pessoas :)